# VB6 DLL Imported in C# .net project - Class not registered

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

I need to use a existing old project into new project in `.net` `c#`

I've done this:

I compiled the project `vb6` in ActiveX DLL, next when I try to add the reference in my project in `Visual Studio .net`, it don't work (it say that not valid assemble).

I looked for this problem in web and I did found some solution and I tried to import the assembly following [directions online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and this work fine now

Now the new problem is that when I debug my project I get

> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0008E6DF-E43B-4DA5-ADFC-2A83E0F04E6C} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Why? How to solve this?

Comment: It may need to be registered with the COM system in order for you to use them. You can run `regsvr32 myactivex.dll` from the command line (in the directory with the control, and with admin privileges) to try and register it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install VB6 dlls. If you don't you need to manually install it. Com Dlls are usually (and VB6 always) self installable.

```
regsvr32 c:\path\dllname.dll
```

For some dll files (not VB6)

```
regsvr32 /i "command line parameters" c:\path\dllname.dll
```

Comment: Hi, I try but when I install obtain "regsvr32 the module was loaded but the entry-point dllregisterserver was not found"

Comment: It's not a com or VB6 server. Tell us more?

Comment: The dll is compiled with Visual Basic 6 compiler and the project type is ActiveX DLL ... The software is old but I need to use a existing code for partial porting in .net

There are other mode for to live together the old dll and .net?

Comment: If you in fact have an ActiveX DLL, you won't get that error in my experience.  You get that error when you try to use regsvr32 with a DLL that isn't a COM DLL.

Comment: Make sure you run the command in a 32 bit command prompt. Or just use the setup program in VB6 which does it for you and is the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! .. I think that I resolved because when I debug solution in same point It work fine.. I reopen the old project VB6 and re-make dll I changed in "Project > Project Properties > Component (tab) " from "no compatible" with "compatible".. I'm in testing , bat I hope that work all.